# Logical ">" and "<" not working inside Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($) {

    var main_content = $('#container'),
     position_top = $('#j_idt7\\:idA').position().top,
     position_left = $('#j_idt7\\:idA').position().left,
     position_width = $('#j_idt7\\:idA').width(),
     position_height = $('#j_idt7\\:idA').height(),
     gen_box = null,
     i  = 1;

    console.log( 'Top Image: ' + position_top + 'px');
    console.log( 'Left Image: ' + position_left + 'px');
    console.log( 'Width Image : ' + position_width + 'px');
    console.log( 'Height Image : ' + position_height + 'px');

    main_content.selectable({ 
                start: function(e) {

                        x_begin = e.pageX,
                        y_begin = e.pageY;

                    },
                stop: function(e) {

                        x_end = e.pageX,
                        y_end = e.pageY;

                        if(x_end > position_left +  position_width )
                            return;


                        if( x_end - x_begin >= 1 ) {
                            width  = x_end - x_begin,
                            height = y_end - y_begin;


                        } else {

                            width  = x_begin - x_end,
                            height =  y_end - y_begin;
                            var drag_left = true;
                        }

                        if(width==0 &amp; height==0)
                            {return;}


                        $(this).append('<div class="gen_box_' + i + '">Test</div>');
                        gen_box = $('.gen_box_' + i);

                        $(gen_box).css({
                            'background' : '#006600',
                             'width'     : width,
                             'height'    : height,
                             'position'  : 'absolute',
                             'left'      : x_begin,
                            'text-align' : 'center',
                            'vertical-align': 'middle',
                             'Opacity'      : '0.3',
                             'top'         : y_begin
                        })
                        .draggable({ grid: [1, 1] })
                        .resizable({
          start: function( event, ui ){
                var x = event.clientX;
                var y = event.clientY;
                if(x!=13)
                console.log('Test');
              }
        });

                        drag_left ? $(gen_box).offset({ left: x_end, top: y_begin }) : false;
                        i++;
                }});
});

</script>
```

Once I put "==" or "!=" in the part :

```
if(x!=13)
console.log('Test');
```

It works without any problem, once I change it by "<" or ">" I got an error in the console saying :

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

This is really weird !! Any help please ?

Comment: Look at the line number that the error console points to... For me it's at this line: `if(width==0 &amp; height==0)`

Comment: Can you narrow down the code to the actual part where it fails? edit: nevermind.

Comment: The part that fails is : if(x>13) console.log('Test'); If I change x>13 by another logical comparator like (==) it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find escape html code here.

[escape html](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Use an editor that is designed for writing code.

It looks like the one you're using (which is it?) is ill-suited to writing code: it seems to be HTML encoding your tokens: `&` is becoming `&amp;` throughout, and so on.

Likely the same is happening with `<` and `>`: they are being HTML-encoded to `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively, and the semicolon in that replacement is causing your syntax error.

Comment: I am developing in JSF, I used first "&&" but I got this message (See : http://screencast.com/t/TxOaHC1bGkwa) because I have XHTML validation, which I changed after by &amp; Everything works fine, but in my code section : if(x!=13) console.log('Test'); works but not if(x > 13) console.log('Test'); which throw the error message